# Does my iOS app contain encryption if I use realm?

Tags: realm, app-store, app-store-connect, realm-mobile-platform

Finally I’m uploading my app to the App Store connect. I’m using the latest version of realmswift and I only created a default realm database and never explicitly tell the realm to use encryption. In this case does my app contain encryption?

Also, sometimes I can see the outputs which looked like realm established an internet connection(I don’t know whether it’s HTTPS or not) and I don’t know why. Maybe to check the realm’s updates?

In this case, does realm really establish a HTTPS connection? What should I choose? Contain or not?

Comment: You didn't specify if you were using local Realm only or RealmSync so I addressed both in my answer. However, - *outputs which looked like realm established an internet connection* - is a little vague. Can you maybe include what that was in your question?

Comment: I’m using local Realm. I’ve seen that output a few days ago but I didn’t save that. That output doesn’t show now, so I’ll update the question whenever I see it again. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

A Realm database is not encrypted unless you tell it to be an encrypted. e.g. you would need to include the following code for the Realm to be encrypted

```
// Generate a random encryption key
var key = Data(count: 64)
_ = key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (pointer: UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) in
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, pointer.baseAddress!) }

var config = Realm.Configuration(encryptionKey: key)
do {
    let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
} catch let error as NSError {
    fatalError("Error opening realm: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

That being said, by default with iOS 8 and above app files are encrypted using NSFileProtection whenever the device is locked.

When it comes to a sync'd Realm, that's a little different as the on-disk files can be encrypted per above, but the sync'd data stored in MongoDB is not encrypted.

A sync'd realm will establish a connection to the sync server (MongoDB) so that will results in internet traffic. Likewise if you're using REST calls to pull data from MongoDB, those will also result in network activity.

Comment: Does sync requests use HTTPS?